# List of consecutive dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have this list:

```
[datetime.date(2020, 12, 21), datetime.date(2020, 12, 22), datetime.date(2020, 12, 23), datetime.date(2020, 12, 24), datetime.date(2020, 12, 25), datetime.date(2020, 12, 26), datetime.date(2020, 12, 27), datetime.date(2020, 12, 28), datetime.date(2020, 12, 29), datetime.date(2020, 12, 30), datetime.date(2020, 12, 31), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 2), datetime.date(2021, 1, 3), datetime.date(2021, 1, 4)]
```

but how do i get it to be [2020-12-21,2020-12-22,...]

Comment: Do you want a list of strings?

Comment: `[2020-12-21,2020-12-22] === [1987,1986]`  ... which im guessing is not what you want...

Comment: yes a list of strings @SilvioMayolo